# How to bind with RADIUS port i.e.1812?

Tags: radius

I am trying to connect to RADIUS port in one of my project. The radius port is 1812 opened on RADIUS server. I added this port to ip table (ip natting) using

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -s 0/0 -d 172.25.X.X/32 --destination-port  1813  -j REDIRECT --to-ports 58440
```

After this when I execute my script and do `netstat -anp` at that time I am unable to see the port opened on my system. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you start radiusd on port 58440 ? You're also according to your iptables command redirecting port 1813 to 58440 but earlier you say the radius post is 1812 - confusion reigns.

Comment: Ya I started it on 58440 and destination port for my radius server is 1812. It was not working with 1812 so I am trying with 1813 but its still not working.

Comment: Why are you changing the listen port and putting in this iptables rule? This appears to be completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

From the information provided, it seems that amongst other things, radiusd is not listening on port 58440. The first thing to do is to fix that.

- Check your logs for relevant error messages.
- Run radiusd in debug mode `radiusd -X`

Once you fix that then it should be easy to solve any additional problems you have.

Comment: There is no error message in logs related to radius

Answer (score 0):

You haven't made it clear which port you expect to see "opened", but if you expect iptables to start listening on 1813 (or 1812), that is not how it works.

You will only see ports that actually have a process bound to them in the kernel. iptables actually redirects each packet to the new port, it doesn't start listening on that port and act as a proxy to the actual port.